# Результат запроса ошибочно рассматривается как шаблон thymeleaf

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

У меня есть контроллер, который должен возвращать List объектов:

```
@Controller
public class LoggingController {

    @Autowired
    private DrawingLoggingService loggingService;

    @GetMapping("/logging/last/{amount}")
    public List<LogRecord> getLastUpdates(@PathVariable int amount) {
        return loggingService.getLastUpdates(amount);
    }

}
```

Но при запросе на /logging/last/1 я получаю:

> Exception processing template "logging/last/1": Error resolving template "logging/last/1", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers

Как сделать, чтобы возвращаемое значение не считалось шаблоном?

Answer (score 0):

Решено, забыл поставить RestController.

Comment: Чтобы дополнить свой вопрос, просим вас воспользоваться опцией редактирования. Кнопку «Опубликовать ответ» следует использовать только для исчерпывающих ответов на вопросы. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/225136)

Comment: Так это же и был ответ на вопрос, а не дополнение к проблеме